# Qemu check if guest is up

Tags: virtualization, qemu

I am in a situation where I have to launch vms using qemu remotely and then keep track of whether the guests are up or not. Is there any way to do this?

I figured out that if I can get the guest ip address, I could resolve it, but I havent yet figured out a way to find this.

I am using a custom version of qemu-0.13 and libvirt is not really an option for me as I need to pass custom parameters to qemu, which I read is not fully supported.

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can provide static ip to your guest machine and continuously ping to check whether it is up.
- using /etc/inittab you can send a packet from guest to host, when guest is up and networking is configured.
- In general guest ip is 10.0.x.y and correspondingly host ip is 10.0.2.2 (from guest' view only), so you can ping host machine as `ping 10.0.2.2` from guest. But from host to guest pinging is not possible. So you can create a reverse ssh tunnel to open a port on host which redirect all the request to that port to guest.